# Appstore multiple update of the same application

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

When I open up the AppStore, under updates, the application thinks that I need to update the same application several times. In this case Command Line Tools is listed several times in a row. How do I remove these multiple entries from the app store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The log of your updates are available in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/App Store/updatejournal.plist
```

The simple solution is to clear the update logs by deleting the mentioned file.

Here is the guide to remove duplicate if you want to keep the update logs.

1. Open Terminal.
2. Convert the `updatejournal.plist` by entering this line `plutil -convert xml1` then drag the `updatejournal.plist` from Finder into Terminal to expand the path, then press <kbd>Return</kbd>. Mine is the following:

   ```
   plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Application\ Support/App\ Store/updatejournal.plist
   ```
3. Open `~/Library/Application\ Support/App\ Store/updatejournal.plist` with your favorite text editor (TextEdit works fine).
4. Find the duplicate update logs. For example, mine is **Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10)**. The point is to delete that entry which is inside the scope of `<dict>`. So you should delete the content between `<dict>` and `</dict>`. Here is line I need to delete. Save the file.

   ```
   <dict>
       <key>__isSoftwareUpdate</key>
       <true/>
       <key>installDate</key>
       <date>2014-10-17T09:55:17Z</date>
       <key>productKey</key>
       <string>031-08844</string>
       <key>release-notes</key>
       <string>Command Line Developer Tools for OS X 10.10</string>
       <key>title</key>
       <string>Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10)</string>
       <key>version</key>
       <string>6.1</string>
   </dict>
   ```
5. Convert the file back to binary1 by entering this line `plutil -convert binary1` and drag the `updatejournal.plist` from Finder, and press <kbd>Return</kbd>. Here is mine in Terminal:

   ```
   plutil -convert binary1 ~/Library/Application\ Support/App\ Store/updatejournal.plist
   ```
6. Open Mac App Store and refresh the **Updates** section. The duplicate line should disappear. Remember to only delete one entry of duplicate file. Imagine that `plist` as a spreadsheet with duplicate lines. Just delete one.

Feel free to leave question in comment if the tutorial is vague.

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear the App Store cache, reboot your Mac and check the App Store.

To clear the cache, open Terminal and copy and paste the following command:

```
open $TMPDIR../C/
```

In the Finder window that will open, locate the `com.apple.appstore` folder and move it to the Trash.

Reboot your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem but did not resolve it by editing "`updatejournal.plist`".

A Japanese [website](http://qiita.com/hshimo/items/5bbc85bb98530c4ac591) provided a solution and it resolved the issue at last. I hope your problem will be fixed also.

This is the essential point: He said it was due to a Spotlight behavior when Spotlight is disabled.

To resolve this, we need to re-enable Spotlight:

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
$ sudo mdutil -E /
```

After rebooted you can disable it again if you desire using:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

Answer (score -2):

Just reboot your mac before updating.